Debugging CAN bus
My Ford S-Max 2014 seems to have issues with the CAN bus, and refuses to start. When hooked up to Fords own diagnostic tools, it complains that the engine ECU doesn't reply. The ECU gets power, and when I test it on the bench it seems to be working alright.
At the moment I haven't got access to a PC-CAN interface. But when hooking up the oscilloscope to the CAN bus in the car, with the ECU in situ, this is what I get:

It seems the recessive voltage differs quite a bit (~0,5V) from the idle state. Is this normal, or could it be an indication to where the fault might lie?

Please post a complete CAN frame. This part you're showing is a valid data frame (https://i.sstatic.net/XITdbCNc.png). I would be more interested in seeing the ACK part of the frame (or lack thereof).
